# Email issue: want to send email without additional window

Tags: iphone, email, sendmail, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I want to send email without showing MFMailComposeViewController. I just want to send email to some sequence of emails (so user should see only my spinner, not MFMailComposeViewController with send button).

The only way to send emails I know is: (but it's not I want)

```
-(void)showMessageController:(id)sender
{

    Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    if (mailClass != nil)
    {
        // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
        if ([mailClass canSendMail])
        {
            [self displayComposerSheet];
        }
        else
        {
            [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
    }
}

// Displays an email composition interface inside the application. Populates all the Mail fields. 
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [appDelegate setNavigationBarTextured:YES navigationBar:picker.navigationBar];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Please, look at my photo!"];

    // Attach an image to the email (mydata - data of the image)
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"Hello!\nPlease, have a look at my photo!";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}




// Launches the Mail application on the device.
-(void)launchMailAppOnDevice
{
//  NSString *recipients = @"mailto:first@example.com?cc=second@example.com,third@example.com&subject=Hello from California!";
    NSString *recipients = @"mailto:subject=Please, look at my photo!";

    NSString *body = @"&body=Hello!\nPlease, have a look at my photo!";

    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

How can I send email without additional screen of MFMailComposeViewController?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think without this it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by Web services. Write a web service that takes message for Email body and receiver's email address, subject etc as parameters and sends mail from backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [PHP script to send email](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How_to_Send_Email_from_a_PHP_Script.htm) and can call the php service call with To, Message, Subject passed from device,

Answer (score 1):

There is no API provided by Apple that would let you send emails without user interaction.