# Sending a mail without using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a contact us form and the given feedback should have to send through a configured mail address.But my main concern is sending the feedback without using `MFMailComposeViewController` compose view.I just need to know whether it's possible to send a feedback as mail by clicking "submit" button without pop up   default mail compose view(`MFMailComposeViewController`).

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: refere http://stackoverflow.com/a/13853967/616094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending mail messages from ios without integrated

> MFMailComposeViewController

you have to have mail client on ios, it is really big work, and the best way for it, is sending your mail message to your server and send recived mail from server. Becouse sending mails from server much more easier than sending it from ios.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to send mail without server, you can use google mail client.  https://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/